# How to auto save file in VSCode on Esc when using Vim extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autosave, vscodevim

I wonder, how can I save current file automatically in VSCode after leaving insert mode in Vim by pressing `Esc` key?

Comment: You could just turn on auto save in VSCode. `File > Toggle Auto Save`

Comment: @Rohmer thanks for your comment! I tried this option a while ago, but it doesn't work as smooth as I wanted it to be. I described my workflow in detail under the corresponding GitHub issue: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/3717#issuecomment-496089728

Comment: no problem! The reason I found this question was because VSCode / VSCodeVim was over saving, during insert mode, every time I entered characters. Maybe some things have changed since your post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replacing `<Esc>` with `<Esc>:w<Enter>` works, but this is probably a slightly more elegant solution (if you have other save commands you'd like to run for example).

```
    "vim.insertModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": [
            "<Esc>"
        ],
        "after": [
            "<Esc>"
        ],
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.files.save"
        ]
    }
],
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add an `insertModeKeyBinding` to the `Esc` key in your `settings.json` like this:

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": ["<Esc>"],
        "after": ["<Esc>", ":", "w", "<Enter>"]
    }
]
```

Note that this will ONLY save if you go from insert mode to normal mode with the `Esc` key.

**edit:** After a bit of testing, I found out you need to stay in insert mode for around 2 seconds after your last change for it to work, otherwise it won't see the `<Esc>` keystroke as a single event.

As a workaround, you could map to `<leader><Esc>`, if you need it instantly.

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": ["<leader>", "<Esc>"],
        "after": ["<Esc>", ":", "w", "<Enter>"]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, this doesn't seem to work. First, I had to use `insertModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive`, otherwise `Esc` stops working at all. Second, even with `insertModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive` it doesn't save the file on `Esc`.

Comment: I tested it on my end and it works as I would expect it (being in insert mode, hitting Esc: leaves insert mode to normal mode and saves the file). Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work for you exactly? Though you are right about the nonRecursive - I actually used nonRecursive myself, just didn't paste the right one.

Comment: You need to wait for ~2 seconds after your last keystroke in insert mode before pressing `Esc`. It just seems to be that way for binding `Esc` in insert mode.

Comment: Thanks! This seem to work now. Waiting for ~2 is a little bit unconvenient, but I guess it deserves separate issue in the Vim plugin. As a side question, how can I set `<leader` to some key like `Alt` or `Cmd`? Default value for `<leader>` is `\` and it just inserts the `\` character in the insert mode.

Comment: `"vim.leader": " "` will set the leader to `Space`, so `Space+Esc` would be "leave insert mode and save". I don't think you can set the leader to the `Meta`-key.

Comment: The delay before this keybinding will be triggered can be controlled by `vim.timeout`. Set it lower to lower the delay needed. For example, `vim.timeout=100` will require only a 100ms gap.

I think there's still a bug somewhere, but `vim.timeout` should resolve your issues.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am banging my head to achieve this.